# E4 Preference Initializer won´t get called

Tags: eclipse, preferences, rcp, e4, initializer

I´m trying to migrate my e3-rcp-app to a e4-rcp-app.

Therefore I need to define my default Preferences. (Not the Pref.Pages)

And by doing and trying so, I  just can´t get my Initializer called. Here Is my initializer-class:

```
public class MyPreferenceInitializer extends AbstractPreferenceInitializer {

public MyPreferenceInitializer (){}

@Override
public void initializeDefaultPreferences() {

Preferences defaults = DefaultScope.INSTANCE.getNode(InspectIT.ID);
          // Set defaults using things like:
          defaults.put("DUMMY", "DUMMYCONTENT");
          try {
            defaults.flush();
        } catch (BackingStoreException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

          //And this other approach to make sure that one of them works
          IPreferenceStore store = InspectIT.getDefault().getPreferenceStore();
          store.setDefault("DUMMY", "DUMMYCONTENT");         
          try {
            ((Preferences) store).flush();
        } catch (BackingStoreException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        //Dummy impl        
       default Preferences....,
    }

}
```

I also got an Activator class with the following structure: (Just posting the relevant methods(?))

```
 public class Activator implements BundleActivator {

        private static BundleContext context;

        static BundleContext getContext() {
            return context;
        }


        private static Activator plugin;

        private volatile ScopedPreferenceStore  preferenceStore;

        public void start(BundleContext context) throws Exception {
            plugin = this;
            Activator.context = context;
            locateRuntimeDir();     
            logListener = new LogListener();
            Platform.addLogListener(logListener);

//access to my initializor
        String text = getPreferenceStore().getDefaultString("DUMMY");
        String text2 = getPreferenceStore().getString("DUMMY");

        }

        public void stop(BundleContext context) throws Exception {

        Activator.context = null;
        plugin = null; 
    }

    public static <E> E getService(Class<E> clazz) {
        ServiceReference<E> reference = context.getServiceReference(clazz);
        if (null != reference) {  

            return context.getService(reference);
        }
        throw new RuntimeException("Requested service of the class " + clazz.getName() + " is not registered in the bundle.");
    }

    public ScopedPreferenceStore getPreferenceStore() {

        if (null == preferenceStore) {
            synchronized (this) {
                if (null == preferenceStore) { 


                    preferenceStore = new  ScopedPreferenceStore(ConfigurationScope.INSTANCE, ID); 
                } 
            } 
        } 
        return preferenceStore;
    }
}
```

The ScopedPreferenceStore I´m using is the one available at: https://github.com/opcoach/e4Preferences/tree/master/com.opcoach.e4.preferences

As well, I declared the plugin.xml Extension like this (I do need this, right?)

```
...
 <extension
         point="org.eclipse.core.runtime.preferences">
      <initializer            class="MyApplication.rcp.preferences.MyPreferenceInitializer ">
      </initializer>
   </extension>
...
```

I´m using Eclipse 4.5.1 on a win7 x64
I googled a lot and found a lot of Threads concerning this, but I just can´t find my mistake =/.
Anyone got a suggestion for why my default preferences initializer won´t get called?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You don't need that `@PostConstruct` on the `start` method. Activators are not injected.

Comment: Thanks, I fixed that, but my Preference initializer still won´t  get invoked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found a solution for this issue. 
Accidentally got over this problem again and the mistake was in the Activator. I wrongly set the ID onto a wrong name. I reset it to my projects name and now it is working!

```
public ScopedPreferenceStore getPreferenceStore() {

    if (null == preferenceStore) {      
        synchronized (this) {
            if (null == preferenceStore) 
            preferenceStore = new ScopedPreferenceStore(ConfigurationScope.INSTANCE, ID); 
        }                   
    } 
    return preferenceStore;
}
```

ID = Project-Name

Answer (score 1):

You must still use the `org.eclipse.core.runtime.preferences` extension point to define the preferences initializer.

```xml
<extension
     point="org.eclipse.core.runtime.preferences">
  <initializer
        class="package.MyPreferenceInitializer">
  </initializer>
</extension>
```

In the initializer use:

```java
@Override
public void initializeDefaultPreferences()
{
  Preferences defaults = DefaultScope.INSTANCE.getNode(Activator.ID);

  // Set defaults using things like:
  defaults.putInt("pref id", 0);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I´m using the extension point (the code just got snipped out, I re-edited my post ;)

Comment: How are you referencing the preferences?

Comment: I reference them in my initializer via

 IPreferenceStore store = InspectIT.getDefault().getPreferenceStore();
        Map<String, String> initializationEntries = PreferenceSupplierDUMMY.getInitializationEntries();
        for(Map.Entry<String, String> entry : initializationEntries.entrySet()) {
            store.setDefault(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
        }         store.setDefault... 
and so on, like i read in this: https://openchrom.wordpress.com/2014/01/11/how-to-handle-preferences-consistently/ 

But I don´t even get this code invoked

Comment: Not sure if that will work. I have added the code I use for the initializer which does work.

Comment: I tried that, but the initializer still doesn´t get a call. It´s like Eclipse is just skipping the whole class. Not the constructor nor the init method gets invoked.

Comment: The initializer is only called when you actually do something that references the preferences. What are you doing to access the preferences?

Comment: Oh, this could be the problem. Actually I was in the migration phasis. In the E3-approach of the app for instance, I try to get a Pref via  String value = preferenceStore.getString(preferenceKey); and the Preference Key is a String with a value on another class.

Comment: I edited my Post to show how I tried to access the default preferences. but there still is no call on the initializer. 
This kind of is, how I should access my values, right ?
Via Debug: In the RootPreferences the getNode method, it return "" because of an EndIndex of -1 (what does this mean?)

Comment: Should be OK. Note: The initializer must be declared in the plugin.xml for the same plugin as the Activator

Comment: Good tip, my product was based on the standard org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt.E4Application. Now I got an own Application (via extension) and a Application-class, doing nothing but starting the app. But still no invokation

Comment: Do I might need a seperate Life Cycle implementation apart from my Activator?